# Rails Activerecord + MySQL query not giving the result I expect

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I need to generate some dashboards and most of those dashboards rely on a sum query in MySQL to work.

here is the rails query in the model:

```
def self.search_three(dyear)
    find_by_sql("SELECT quantity, model,
SUM(IF(status = 'Completed',quantity,0)) AS Comp,
SUM(IF(status = 'Shipped',quantity,0)) AS Ship,
SUM(IF(status = 'Cart Submitted',quantity,0)) AS CS,
SUM(quantity) AS total
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(needby) = '#{dyear}'
GROUP BY model")
  end
```

it works, but the problem is that the output in the rails console is not what I expect to get to the dashboard.

[#, #, #] that is the output if I assign dyear (which is an input from somewhere else) to 2015.

However, in the MySQL workbench when I do:

```
SELECT quantity,
SUM(IF(status = 'Completed',quantity,0)) AS Comp,
SUM(IF(status = 'Shipped',quantity,0)) AS Ship,
SUM(IF(status = 'Cart Submitted',quantity,0)) AS CS,
SUM(quantity) AS total
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(needby) = '2015'
GROUP BY model
```

I get

{|
  !Qty ||  !Comp ||!Ship||  !CS   ||    !total 
|-
|40    ||  8810  ||  0  ||  1081  ||     19181  ||  Connector
|-
|118   ||  318   ||  0  ||  0     ||     955    ||  EU Cords
|-
|256   ||  548   ||  0  ||  0     ||     3944   ||  US Cords
|}

what I need the graph to display is that total column and what the graph will display is the aforementioned incorrect quantities.

How do I get the rails query to use the AS total for the output instead of just the first column?

Comment: I guess the mediawiki tables layout thing doesn't work.  Bottom line is that the rails query is using the first column under quantity with values of 40,118, and 256 instead of using the total that is the sum of all those quantities.

How can I make it use the total column (which is a temporary column) for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was very close;

```
def self.search_three(dyear)
    find_by_sql("SELECT model,
SUM(IF(status = 'Completed',quantity,0)) AS Comp,
SUM(IF(status = 'Shipped',quantity,0)) AS Ship,
SUM(IF(status = 'Cart Submitted',quantity,0)) AS CS,
SUM(quantity) AS quantity
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(needby) = '#{dyear}'
GROUP BY model")
  end
```

That mostly gives me the output I expected; though it does show the following:

```
[#<Order id: nil, quantity: 19181, model: "Connector">, #<Order id: nil, quantity: 955, model: "EU Cords">, #<Order id: nil, quantity: 3944, model: "US Cords">]
```

I think the Order id portion being in there might be problematic for chartkick, but that is another post later probably.

Comment: turns out chartkick gem doesn't like find_by_sql, but that is okay; I refactored the code as follows:

  `code def self.search_three(dyear)
               select('model').where("status IN ('Completed','Shipped','Cart Submitted') AND YEAR(needby) = '#{dyear}'").group('model').sum(:quantity)
  end`